# django: on pypy, psyco, unladen swallow or cpython, which one is the fastest?

Tags: python, django, compiler-construction, comparison, benchmarking

Has anyone tried to compare those python implementations?

- pypy
- psyco
- unladen swallow (is it dead?)
- cpython

I am planning to squeeze something more from my server.

Setup:

- Django 1.3
- Python 2.7
- Psycopg2 1.4
- apache 2
- mod_wsgi
- and... Windows server

I am not a windows fanboy, but it has to be :{ There is some legacy code working on it.

Comment: I bet lots of people have compared them, but likely not on your specific application.

Comment: PyPy won't work with mod_wsgi, but there are good WSGI servers that will run faster on PyPy than on CPython.

Comment: "but likely not on your specific application" means you should run actual benchmarks on your actual application and report the results.

Comment: The speed of your underlying tools is not going to be where your bottleneck is. You should be looking at the performance of your specific application code and your use of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/06/06/django-and-pypy.html links to some benchmarks that compare pypy and cpython using a small django framework (so I guess it just benchmarks how long it takes to create a view).  You may be able to use the same benchmark with other frameworks, though it's far from being an all inclusive speed test.

I believe unladen swallow was discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should considerate is the C extensions. Different implementations require different extension ways. At present, the CTYPES may be the most common one.

So I recommend you take CPython, in case of possible C extensions.